# functions.php script breaks when variable isn't hard coded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I have written a jQuery script that takes a JSON encoded list produced with this function is run in my theme's functions.php and creates a playlist for my jPlayer. However, the script only works when the `$file` variable is hard coded (for example, `OH0400`). But I need it to pick up the `$file` variable based on the page being loaded. But when I switch to this method (using URL), the script says the JSON is null.

I've run the script in multiple ways and the output between the hard coded `$file` and the variable based `$file` appear to be the same. Why do I get null when I make the switch?

Here's the PHP in my theme functions.php.

```
 function MyjPlayerList(){
    $url = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    $file = strtoupper($url[2]);
    //$file = 'OH0400';

    $filename = '/dir/oralhistory/mp3files/'.$file.'*.mp3';
    $FILES = glob( $filename );
          foreach( $FILES as $key => $mp3 )  {
          $mp3 = str_replace( '/dir/oralhistory/mp3files/', '',$mp3);           
          $FILE_LIST[ $key ][ 'title' ] = $mp3;
          $FILE_LIST[ $key ][ 'mp3' ] = 'http://websiteurl.org/mp3files/'.$mp3;   
    } 

    $myjplayerdata = json_encode( $FILE_LIST ); 
    header ( 'Content-type: application/json' );    
    echo $myjplayerdata;
    exit;
    die();
     };
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    ajax_player = function() {
        jQuery('div#player').load('/js/player.html' , function() {
            var cssSelector= {
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            };
        var playlist = [];
        var options = {
            swfPath: "/js/Jplayer.swf",
            supplied: "mp3",
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true
        };
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
         jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" ,
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "text json",
                  data: { action: "MyjPlayerList"},
                  success:(function(data) {
                jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
                        myPlaylist.add(value); // add each element in data in myPlaylist
                      console.log(data);        
                })
                  })//function (data) close

                })//ajax close  
        })//jquery.load  
}//ajax_player
```

Comment: just because things appear to be the same doesn't mean they are. consider invisible characters like spaces. e.g. what does `echo strlen($file)` show once you've done your explode? is it more than the 6 you'd expect to get from `OH0400`?

Comment: Marc, i get a 6 for both ways.

Comment: then unless you've got some ultra-funky character set issue, or are mis-seeing `0` and `O`, then there's no way your fixed string could be different from the dynamically retrieved one.

Comment: well, that's frustrating, but at least makes me feel more sane.

Comment: do a something like `if($file != 'OH0040') { die("not equal") }` or something. Then at least you'd KNOW something is different. If they are identical, then there's no way PHP would cause the glob() results to come out differently. e.g. `$x = 2;` v.s. `$x = 1 + 1;` will both produce identical $x's, even though you used  a constant for one, and an expression for the other. PHP will just store `2`, regardless of how that `2` was produced.

Comment: so if they aren't different, then the problem is in my javascript?

Comment: well, that's basic debugging. if the values are the same, then see what happens before you jsonencode, e.g. `var_dump($FILE_LIST)`. put in debug output at each stage and see where things start looking different. that'll be where the problem is. If php's output is identical in both cases, then start looking at the JS... though I can't see how JS would care WHAT path the php was working with on the server.

Comment: got it! thanks Marc! turns out that what I get when i run the script & what i get when I call the script w/ javascript are different. it's trying to glob admin-ajax.php instead of the URL. not sure how to fix it, but at least i know the problem now.

Comment: Use `absolute` url instead, `get_bloginfo('url') . '/...'`.

Comment: Sheikh, maybe i'm not following you, but it appears to just gets me 'http://website.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

Comment: Side notes: this probably deserves [to be in a plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) & a [working example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54875).

Comment: is the javascript code in a PHP template or in a JS file?

Comment: the javascript code is in it's own file. php is in functions.php. And yes, hind sight 20/20, it should have been a plug-in. but this was my first stab at something like this, so it was bound to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the debugging of Marc,turns out that what I get when i run the script in page & what i get when I call the script w/ javascript are different. it's trying to glob admin-ajax.php instead of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check the character encoding you're using. That could be the problem.